# Formula to Find if Number between a Range in 2 Columns and then Offset 1 column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, formula, excel-2007

I would like to write an Excel formula that looks at 3 columns and grabs value of the 1st column based on if the search value is in columns 2 or columns 3.

```
1st Column 2nd Column 3rd Column
a      1              5
b      6              10
c      11             15
```

```
Search Value 1: 13           Result: c
Search Value 2: 6            Result: b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below formula-

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$3,MAX(($B$1:$B$3<=B6)*($C$1:$C$3>=B6)*(ROW($A$1:$A$3))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Harun24HR! This worked perfectly!!

Comment: Glad to know it helps.

Comment: Quick question - I also wanted to build an =IFERROR for when B6 and B7 were empty, looking at the next column. I have the following but it is not doing what it should - "{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$3,MAX(($B$1:$B$3<=B6)*($C$1:$C$3>=B6)*(ROW($A$1:$A$3)))),INDEX($A$1:$A$3,MAX(($B$1:$B$3<=A6)*($C$1:$C$3>=A6)*(ROW($A$1:$A$3))))}". Is the logic correct?